# Disable PHP eval in Virtualhost per location

Tags: php, apache, eval, httpd.conf, suhosin

I have successfully installed suhosin in my server and I'm blocking the devil PHP `eval` function on some virtualhosts with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html/www.example.com>
         #SUHOSIN
         php_admin_value suhosin.executor.disable_eval On
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I need to enable eval on some specific URL since it is used by the platform on some specific cases. I've tried the following:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html/www.example.com>
         # SUHOSIN
         php_admin_value suhosin.executor.disable_eval On
    </Directory>
    <Location "/some/path">
        # Reenable eval for this path
        php_admin_value suhosin.executor.disable_eval Off
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And also with the tag `LocationMatch`, with no success (it's like if it was not there: no effect at all).

Any ideas how can I have this directive working just for a specific path?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not using SUHOSIN, I solved with different php.ini files for each website.
Something like:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
[...]
PHPINIDir /path/to/specificinifile
[...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe not the cleanest since the php.ini file has lots of configurations and it might turn difficult to maintain, but I will try afterwards. Hope it helps, thank you!

Comment: Aaah. I'm sorry but this doesn't work. The PHPINIDir is not allowed in between LocationMatch tags : (